# Display VideoFrame on screen

Tags: c#, uwp

Well, I'm stucked in displaying the VideoFrame.

```
VideoFrame inputVideoFrame, croppedFace=null;
croppedFace = new VideoFrame(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, (int)width, (int)height, BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore);
await inputVideoFrame.CopyToAsync(croppedFace, cropBounds, null);
```

I want to display the VideoFrame type, inputVideoFrame on xaml. (on image or captureelement)

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
SoftwareBitmap previewFrame = inputVideoFrame.SoftwareBitmap;

var sbSource = new SoftwareBitmapSource();
await sbSource.SetBitmapAsync(previewFrame);

// Display it in the Image control
PreviewFrameImage.Source = sbSource;
```

See this [sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/CameraGetPreviewFrame/cs/MainPage.xaml.cs).

Comment: Wow, this is what i've done just few minuates ago and it worked :) you wrote the same thing holly... what a coincidence!!!! thank you anyways!!!!!

Comment: ;), so this answer is double-verified.